# sudo su error messege through LDAP

Tags: sudo, ldap, sles

I managed to get an authentication through ldap on my SLES 12 machine, but I can't set a certain group as sudoers.
My suders entry looks as follows:

```
%LNX-ADMIN-vibe3 ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

But all I get when trying `sudo su` is

```
*Username* is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
```

I tried set the `nsswitch.conf` to `sudoers: files sss` but then the error message changes:

```
*Username* is not allowed to run sudo on *Servername*.  This incident will be reported.
```

So I also tried adding following attributes to my LDAP Group

```
cn=LNX-ACCESS-vibe3

object Class    sudoRole 
sudeCommand     ALL
sudoHost        ALL
sudo user       %LNX-ACCESS-vibe3
```

But still no effect. I think the `nsswitch.conf` is the one controlling the location from with the `sudoers` file is getting his information. So currently its set to ldap so it accesses the `ldap.conf` file. If any further information about the LDAP tree is required, please ask.

Comment: try enclosing in quote `"%LNX-ADMIN-vide3"`

Comment: unfortunatly that didnt help. tried it with bith nsswitch options

Comment: is LNX-ACCESS-vibe3 an LDAP group?  what does `grep ^group /etc/nsswitch.conf` and `getent group LNX-ACCESS-vibe3` show?

Comment: Yes it is. and here are my outputs:
`grep ^group /etc/nsswitch.conf
group:  files sss
group_compat:   files`

and no output with `getent group LNX-ACCESS-vibe3`

Comment: I assume that the user you are using is in that group? Also, changes to groups requires you to log out and back in.

Comment: No, the user I was using is the root user, but I dont see how that changes anything. I also rstartet the machine a couple of times